# Calculation of factorial of large numbers in c using arrays

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, factorial

I am trying to calculate factorial of very large numbers in c like 100!..by dynamically allocating memory after calculating the number of digits in factorial:
 My code is:

```
int main()
{
    int n,q,i,j,z,t,d;
    float p=0.0;
    printf("Enter the number whose factorial is to be calculated:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //calculating number of digits
    for(j=2;j<=n;j++)
    p=p+log10(j);
    d=(int)p+1;
    printf("No of digits in the factorial are:%d\n",d);
    int *a;
    a=(int *)malloc(d*sizeof(int));//allocation of memory 
    a[0]=1;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)//initialize array
    a[i]=0;
    p=0.0;
    for(j=2;j<=n;j++)
    {
        q=0;
        p=p+log10(j);
        z=(int)p+1;
        for(i=0;i<z;i++)
        {
           t=(a[i]*j)+q;
           q=t/10;
           a[i]=t%10;   
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=d-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its providing correct answers upto 40! but not after that!What is wrong with my solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time limit of a c program while calculating factorial of numbers in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586842/time-limit-of-a-c-program-while-calculating-factorial-of-numbers-in-c)

Comment: @PaulR I asked the question u are referring to and im having doubt in its execution as i tested with multiple cases.

Comment: Instead of allocating and clearing (which you do in the slowest way possible) the allocated memory, you can do it in one single step with the [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) function.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: you're correct but my doubt is that the algorithm is not working above 40!Why so is there something wrong?

Comment: You should really edit your code to make it more readable. That for-loop looks weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably because of this loop:

```
for(i=1;i<n;i++)//initialize array
```

In the loop you clear the `n - 1` entries of the allocated memory, but you allocate memory for `d` entries. If `n - 1` is larger than `d` then you write outside the allocated memory, which causes undefined behavior. If `n - 1` is smaller than `d` then you leave some memory uninitialized which also is undefined behavior when you access it.

You should clear all of the memory, either by using your loop, by using [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) or by using [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) when allocating.

Answer (score 1):

may be you can use memset in case not quite interested in calloc, also I guess null check is mandatory

so instead of this looping

```
a=(int *)malloc(d*sizeof(int));//allocation of memory 
    a[0]=1;
for(i=1;i<n;i++)//initialize array
    a[i]=0;
```

a simple call

```
a=(int *)malloc(d*sizeof(int));//allocation of memory 
if(a == NULL)
{
   printf("OOM Error");
   exit(1);
}
memset(a, 0 , d*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
int i,j,n,m=0;

scanf("%d",&n);

int arr[2000];
int temp=0;
int inter=1;
arr[0]=1;

for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{ 
  for(j=0;j<=m;j++)
  {
    inter=arr[j]*i+temp;
    arr[j]=inter%10;
    temp=inter/10;
       if( temp>0 && j==m )
       m++;
   }
 }
for(i=m;i>=0;i++)
{
 printf("%d",arr[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```